# PHP end date calculation

Tags: php, date

i have a situation where i know the start date and the durration of an event in days ,  how can i calculate the end date ?
i found  topics on how to calculate the duration between two dates but nothing in my case 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318974/how-do-you-calculate-an-end-time-based-on-start-time-and-duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date(strtotime("+" .durationInDays." days")[,startDate])

Comment: Not meaning to be rude , but your answer has an error , the second date() parameter is useless unless you are doing some calculation back in time eg. for last year  :) 
date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+" .$durationInDays." days"));

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP *Date->modify* method (also know as *DateTime::modify*).
Because I also find the description on the PHP site not very obvious I provide an example to show the simple and readable code:

```
<?php
$currentDate = new DateTime('2012-12-19');
$currentDate->modify('+2 day');
printf("\nThe maya dooms day is at %s ?!", 
          date_format( $currentDate, 'D, M d Y'));
?>
```

In the modify argument you can (also) use:

- day
- week
- month
- year

And much more, but do you need more?